# Ubuntu NET:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, firefox, ubuntu-16.04

Recently I have been using ubuntu and as a CS student, i enjoy it quite a bit. unfortunately, as I am living in student halls and I have to use the given wifi and am not allowed to set up my own sub-network.(The halls have disconnected our ethernet ports)

After a week of using ubuntu perfectly fine. I keep getting  NET:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in chrome. Also, I have tried firefox but again I am getting "this connection is not secure". I understand that I have to log into an account to access wifi/internet access but any browser in Linux won't let me. Previously I was not asked to log in but my internet worked perfectly fine.

What I have already done so far to try and resolve this issue.

1. Set the correct date and time for my location.
2. Deleted all browsing history twice. (This got the internet to work and 10 seconds later it came up with the same error.)
3. This [How do I deal with NET:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1083766/how-do-i-deal-with-neterr-cert-authority-invalid-in-chrome)
4. And this http://www.toppctech.com/fix-net-err-cert-authority-invalid-error/ (Fix 1 does not exist in my version of chrome)

I am using chrome v54.02840.90(64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Comment: What websites? What information does Chrome give about the certificate? It sounds like a man-in-the-middle attack and you shouldn't be accepting those certificates -- and if it's your school administration trying to intercept your SSL connections, you should complain and do not use their network.

Comment: if you look at the certificate, is it associated with a anti-malware system installed on your box? many of them perform a personal man-in-the-middle, so that they can scan traffic in HTTPS tunnels to keep malware from hiding evidence it exists via encryption.