# Can't get full content of the site on windows 7 due to NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet, url

I try to access the site ( https://dnevnik.ru/ ) on windows 7 32 bit.
On windows 10 everything is ok. It looks like as it should be

[image]

But when I try to open it on windows 7 it shows me that the site is not safe. Then I click on "Proceed to the site anyway". After that only text content is displayed.

[image]

I had old version of Google Chrome and updated it to the version 87.0.4280.88. But the result was the same.

Chrome Dev Tools there are a lot of `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` errors.

[image]

How can I get full content of that site on windows 7 ?

Comment: If you enable CAPI2 logging in the event log does that show any problems when you visit the site on Windows 7? To break it down, I might also be interested to open the Dev Tools (F12) of the browser, look at the Network tab to see which requests are failing.

Comment: @HelpingHand ok. I added the screenshot with log errors.

Comment: Is Windows up to date with patches? Did the event log I mention, once enabled give you anything to go on?

Comment: See if [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1083768/8672) helps.